# Magento 1.9 print invoice the characters are shown split and reverse

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf, fonts, invoice-pdf

I have changed the font of pdf invoices to support Arabic characters, but the problem is the characters are split and reversed?  Any suggested solution please Help!

[image]

Comment: any one fix this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the instructions here:
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Programming/Invoice-Print-PDF-of-admin-does-not-support-the-Chinese-language/td-p/88630.